# UISearchBarController appearance bug with UItableView and UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, ios9, uisearchbar

I have a UISearhBarController whose search bar is in a uiTableView.tableHeaderView which is in a view with a navigation bar.

I'm setting a custom colour for the search bar like so;

```
self.searchController.searchBar.searchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyleMinimal;
self.searchController.searchBar.backgroundImage = [UIImage imageWithColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
self.searchController.searchBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
self.searchController.searchBar.translucent = NO;
self.searchController.searchBar.tintColor = [UIColor ACYellowColor];
```

And I change the colour so that it fits in with the navigation bar when it is active:

```
- (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
[[UITextField appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil] setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
self.searchController.searchBar.backgroundImage = [UIImage imageWithColor:[UIColor ACBlackColor]];
self.searchController.searchBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor ACBlackColor];
}

- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    [[UITextField appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil] setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    self.searchController.searchBar.backgroundImage = [UIImage imageWithColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    self.searchController.searchBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
}
```

Sometimes, when the search bar is active, on rotation, it will turn gray. It only seems to do this when transitioning to portrait and only on iOS 9. It also happens when I don't modify the colour in searchBarTextDidBeginEditing or searchBarCancelButtonClicked (so it goes from white to gray).

Here's a [video](https://youtu.be/8ff0lEESHHQ) that illustrates the issue.

Comment: Please edit your question so it actually is a question. Right now it looks more like a bug report

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be the scope bar (which I wasn't using).
Settings it's background to be clear fixed the issue

```
self.searchController.searchBar.scopeBarBackgroundImage = [UIImage imageWithColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```